# What is File Table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have created a new database using SQL Server 2012 Management Studio. Under table tab it is showing "File Tables". What are these File Tables, and what are the pros and cons of it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is where you can store files and documents but you access them from Windows applications as if they were stored in the file system.

You can read the whole explanation in windows doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetables-sql-server

Regards.